# How to get a return type from a Dao? With parameter. [no LiveData!]

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room

I want to get an int value from a Query.
For this I think I need an Async Task because it should not run on main-thread...

Is this even possible?

For now I have this code:

```
    public void getLabelColorWithID(int pLabelID){

    GetLabelColorWithIDAsyncTask task = new GetLabelColorWithIDAsyncTask((labelDao));
    task.delegate = this;
    task.execute(pLabelID); //https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Room_Database_and_Repository_Tutorial

}

private void getLabelColorWithIDAsyncFinished(int color){
    this.labelColor.setValue(color);
}

public MutableLiveData<Integer> getLabelColorWithID(){

    return labelColor;
}



    private static class GetLabelColorWithIDAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{

    private LabelDao labelDao;

    private LabelRepository delegate = null;


    private GetLabelColorWithIDAsyncTask(LabelDao labelDao){
        this.labelDao = labelDao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(final Integer... integers) {

        return labelDao.getLabelColorWithID(Integer.parseInt(integers[0].toString()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer color) {
        delegate.getLabelColorWithIDAsyncFinished(color);

    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jusaw.gonnado, PID: 27101
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.jusaw.gonnado.LabelRepository.getLabelColorWithID(LabelRepository.java:70)
    at com.jusaw.gonnado.LabelViewModel.getLabelColorWithID(LabelViewModel.java:52)
```

...

I would like to return just an Integer.

I need the color for a list where I want to color the thing, after what label it has. Is it possible to write a query where I also ask the label color with the thing?

Comment: why you use `Integer.parseInt(integers[0].toString())`, integers[0] is already an Integer. and can you post the code of `getLabelColorWithID ` it seems the error comes from that function.

Comment: BTW, if you need to query multiple times, I think you should better use `ThreadPool` rather than create an asyn task each time.